# Convergent or divergent when limit is found?

Tags: limits

For the series, I need to find whether it is converging or diverging.
Here is my attempt:

$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x - 1}{x + 1} $

. . .

$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1 - \frac{2}{x + 1}$

Therefore I calculated the limit to be 1. Which is converging, right?

This attempt looks so wrong, so I have tried the ratio test, but they don't simplify (at least with my brain).

The question is, is this a valid method, taking limits of a series? It seems fairly wrong to do so, as it's not continuous(I think???).

Comment: No, because the limit is different of zero, the series diverges.

Comment: Is x need to be n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, we say it's convergent of the limit of the partial sums $s_k := \sum_{n=0}^k a_n$ converge to some finite limit. What you've shown is that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1$, NOT that $\lim s_k = 1$. By the [$n$th term test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) your series diverges.

e: I don't understand what you mean by "it's not continuous", or how it applies what you're trying to do...

Comment: Ah..does it mean that, provided it was done correctly, it means that the series is diverging?So what I've done is a completely different 'test' to the one I intended ?(I didn't even realize that this was even a 'test'...)

Comment: Yes, your series diverges.

Comment: Oh, forgot one thing:  if x is really big, shouldn't the series converge to 1 though? like,,, 100000 - 1/ 100000 + 1 = 1.. Or is my limit wrong? :(

Comment: You're still getting the $s_k$ confused with the $a_n$. A series is a SUM of its terms. You're right that the individual terms go to one; but if you're adding infinitely many ones...

Comment: OH........Yes...okay I get it :). I've never touched/seen series before, so its very confusing! thanks!

Comment: @Topstar [This series of videos by Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/seq_induction) are very good at explaining sequences, series, convergence tests, etc